# How can I split a string delimited with multiple characters?

Tags: regex, string, oracle

I'm trying to split a string that's delimited by "space-quote-space" ( ' ) between the values.

The regex is run in an Oracle PL/SQL select statement, [but I believe it's pretty good with the regex it allows](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm#1006817)

The strings look like this:

```
FINA 233ff ' BLA 33333333 ' FRED ' O'GLADSON ' 99 LEFT RD ' FLINDERS MI ' 9999 ' 0499999999 ' HERE ARE SOME NOTES $9999.00 OLD THING SD2232DD (LEFT) PLS SEE JOHN
```

While I can split the string based on the single quote easy enough -

```
[^']+
```

...it hits the quote in the middle of the surname (O'GLADSON). To make it easier I can add in a single quote on the start or the end. I can also trim the results afterward, if I can get the split right. What's the correct regex?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need :

```
([:space:]''[:space:])   //single quote need to be escaped
```